# FileNotFoundException on local webserice at HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()

Tags: java, web-services, httpurlconnection

First of all, yes, there are multiple question on SO with this exact premise. But none of the answers worked for me, so I'll ask with my specific problem.

I have a webservice that runs locally. This webservice has a method that should allow you to try logging in. If you succeed, it sends the user information back. If you don't, you get an invalid user object.

```
@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {  
   Dao dao = new Dao();  

   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   @Path("/login") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public User login(final LoginBean params){
       //return new User();

       User u = new User();
       u.setEmail(params.email);
       u.setPassword(params.password);
      return dao.login(u);
   }
}
```

This specific method works fine in Postman. I call it, get a 200 response, and a complete user object as xml.

But when I call it from my code, it throws a FileNotFoundException on the line conn.getInputStream();

```
public class UserDAO {

    public static User login(User user) {
        String uri = "http://192.168.2.22:8080/Roommanagement/rest/UserService/login";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);

            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
            conn.setDoOutput( true );
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
            conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/xml"); 
            //conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
            //conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
            conn.setUseCaches( false );

            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);

            jc.createMarshaller().marshal(user, conn.getOutputStream());

            //XMLEncoder xmlE = new XMLEncoder(conn.getOutputStream());
            //xmlE.writeObject(user);
            //xmlE.close();

            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
            java.io.InputStream streamXML;
            streamXML = conn.getInputStream();
            User returnedUser =
            (User) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(streamXML);
            conn.disconnect();
            return returnedUser;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new User();
    }
}
```

You can see a couple of things I've tried from the commented out lines, none of them made any difference.

What am I doing wrong? I assume the service itself is fine since all my manual calls done from Postman work as expected.

Comment: You have to use JAXB for both the input and the output.  `XMLEncoder` is for bean serialization, which produces entirely different XML than JAXB conversion.

Comment: I'm tried it, but I get the exact same problem. I can update the code in the question, if it makes a difference.

Comment: Try for debugging to add `conn.getResponseCode()` instead / before `getInputStream`. In most cases, when getInputStream throws `FileNotFoundException` what actually happened: You got a 404 from the server. In this case, continue debugging with `getErrorStream`. You are calling a RestService, don't you (rest/UserService/login)? In this case, the post-method might respond only with the http-header and no http-body, as it is the rest default for the post method (as far as i know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a potential problem here:
Your operation excepts a `LoginBean` instance, but you supply it a `User` instance:

```
public User login(final LoginBean params){
```

and

```
public static User login(User user) {
  ....
  jc.createMarshaller().marshal(user, conn.getOutputStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

Many things can be happening.

The first thing that you have to do is to get the response code and test it.

```
con.getResponseCode();
```

Is a good practice to get the content type before trying to convert to XML. Just print it in plain String.

Treat the response according to response code received. Here some code that you can use as example.

```
if ((200 <= con.getResponseCode() && con.getResponseCode() <= 299)) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));
        String response = new String();
        for (String line; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null; response += line);
        System.out.println(response);
    } else {
        System.out.println();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() == null) {
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            } else {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getErrorStream())));
        String response = new String();
        for (String line; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null; response += line);
        System.out.println(response);
        throw new WebServiceException(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the code that makes the actual HTTP request. You need to call the connect method to make the actual request.

```
conn.connect()
```

Rest of the code looks fine.